# Optimize Sql Query remove SELECT clause and use JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql-server, join, left-join, outer-join

**Not an SQL Expert**

I am trying to come up with an SQL query to do a JOIN on 4 tables. I am using MySQL, I have a working query but it needs to be optimized.

These are my four tables as show:

**customer**

```
+--------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+-------+
| id        | first_name    | last_name | email | zip | phone | type_id  |
+--------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+-------+
```

**order**

```
+--------------+---------+---
| id        | product_name   |
+--------------+---------+---
```

**customer_order**

```
+--------------+---------+
| customer_id  | order_id|
+--------------+---------+
```

**customer_type**

```
+--------------+----
| type_id   | type | 
+--------------+----
```

**Solution 1:**

This is the mysql query that I could come up with and works. But it has a `Select` clause in between and I don't like it. I would want to replace that with a `JOIN` and tried many things but I am getting syntax error.

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.id AS cus_id,
                c.email,
                c.phone,
                c.zip,
                c.last_name,
                c.first_name,
                coo.product_name,
                ct.type AS cus_type
FROM customer c
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (SELECT o.product_name,
          co.customer_id
   FROM customer_order co,
   order o
   WHERE co.customer_id = o.id) coo ON coo.customer_id = c.id
JOIN customer_type ct ON ct.type_id = c.type_id
```

**Solution 2:**

I re-factored the above query to partially replace the `WHERE` condition with a `JOIN` instead but this is still the same as the above query, works as I want it to.

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.id AS cus_id,
                c.email,
                c.phone,
                c.zip,
                c.last_name,
                c.first_name,
                coo.product_name,
                ct.type AS cus_type
FROM customer c
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (SELECT o.product_name,
          co.customer_id
   FROM customer_order co
   JOIN
   order o ON co.customer_id = o.id) coo ON coo.customer_id = c.id
JOIN customer_type ct ON ct.type_id = c.type_id
```

Can someone please guide me how I can replace the `SELECT` query which I am using in between with a `JOIN`.

Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this.........

```
SELECT c.id AS cus_id, c.email, c.phone, c.zip, 
c.last_name, c.first_name, o.product_name, ct.type AS cus_type
FROM customer c
INNER JOIN customer_type ct ON ct.type_id = c.type_id
LEFT  JOIN customer_order co ON co.customer_id = c.id
LEFT  JOIN order o ON co.order_id = o.id
```

Comment: Thanks for the query, but it's not working as the one, which I have. It returns less number of rows. Is there something that you can update?

Comment: Just to give you a feedback there can be NULL product_name value in the order table, which are the missing rows.